# Incidence angle of geographic cordination

Tags: coordinate-system, sentinel-1, radar, insar

I am processing Sentinel 1 data with ENVI SARscape (can process also with gamma if it helps me) for earthquake inversion. Due to the fact that I want to use ascending and descending acquisition, I am working with the earth coordination system and not the satellite one. Therefore I need to know the incidence angle of the ascending and descending track for specific geographic coordination points.

So I think my question is: How do I convert the geographic coordination to the satellite coordination system (for ascending or descending)?

After knowing the coordination of a point in the satellite coordination system calculating the incidence angle is clear.

Comment: after researching the web for answers I got to the Sentinal-1 orbit file which contains the satellite coordination and from that, I can project the geographic coordination to the satellite one. the problem is I don't understand what kind of coordination system the file is displing.  example from the file

Comment: sorry bat here an example for the Sentinel-1 orbit file [link](https://gist.github.com/yohaiMagen/03e1ce4483127b4661048dea46470c15) how do I convert the coordination in the file to geographic one?

Comment: The metadata contains a file with the incidence angles per scene which you could use to interpolate the global incidence angle of each pixel. The local incidence angle would require knowledge of the topography e.g. by using a DEM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENVI SARscape has an option part of the geocoding of the interferometry image to output an local incidence angle map. taking to account the satellite geometry and dem.

in the ENVI classic:

SARscape-->basic-->geocoding-->geocdind and radiometric calibration
in this tool you need to check the Local incidence Angel box [image]

from that, you get an output fileName_geo_lia a raster that its values are the local incidence angle.